# How to know if current logged in user is tenant admin using graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, odata

I have a requirement to check if logged in user is tenant admin or not using MS graph api. I tried below https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ and get below response and there is nothing related to roles in below response. How to determine whether the below "id" is tenant Admin or not?

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "",
    "givenName": "",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": "",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "",
    "preferredLanguage": ,
    "surname": "",
    "userPrincipalName": "",
    "id": "Guid"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf` to implement your requirement.

If the first item of the `value` in the api response data is `Company Administrator`, the logged in user is admin. If not, the user is not admin (shown as below screenshot).
[image]

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf  this doesn't returns the object shown in screenshot

Comment: Hi @DeepakKothari If the api response nothing, it means the user isn't admin and do not belong to any group. Is your response data like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k5Y5.png) ?

Comment: Hi @Hury Shen, I do not get empty response, I do get a huge response.[https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEJGU.png]]. I think I need to test other way , i.e login as tenant admin and check if I get the response as you got.

Comment: @DeepakKothari It seems the user belongs to many groups(or be assigned with many roles). Could you please click the `+` to show the first item under the `value` field ?

Comment: @DeepakKothari If you can't expand the items under `value` field, you can use this api `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf?$top=5` to show top 5 items.

Comment: @DeepakKothari Then check if the first item is `Company Administrator`. If yes, the user is admin. If no, the user is not admin.

Comment: I get this for one of the tenant [![For Example][https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwyOw.png]], I think I need to create a tenant admin and test it after logging in with that id. How to create a tenant admin, Do you have any references?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224952/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-deepak-kothari).

Comment: @DeepakKothari, I am getting displayName as NULL. How did you add the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an already answered question, but i found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/67411/graph-api-best-way-to-check-admin-status) that you can also check if `roleTemplateId` is equal to `62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10` to determine if your user have admin rights. (which I think is quite better than checking the `displayName`)

And please note that your App will need more permissions than just `User.Read` to receive all the information. You will at least need `Directory.Read.All`.